# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo on google map Activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-layout

I have been trying to use a google map fragment. The project works fine without the custom info window that I'm trying to add for every marker, but when I added the info window I got a NullPointerException. As shown here:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.couchbase.grocerysync, PID: 6820
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.couchbase.grocerysync/com.couchbase.grocerysync.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
```

Below is the layout file:

```
<com.couchbase.grocerysync.MapWrapperLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map_relative_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<AutoCompleteTextView
android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="10"
android:layout_weight="1.06"
android:text="Please enter your place" >
<requestFocus />
</AutoCompleteTextView>


<Button
android:id="@+id/Bsearch"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="90dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:onClick="onSearch"
android:text="Search" />
</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

this is the setUpMapIfNeeded() method, called from the onCreate and where the error appears:

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null) {
        AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);

        autoCompView.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item));
        autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this); //here is the error!
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: can you post your java code as well?

Comment: I just edited me question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mapFragment is returning null. In your xml you are using MapFrgament and in Java you are inflating SupportMapFragment.
Replace this line in your xml

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment".
```

with

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment".
```

Should work.